# How to link to a page created with views

Tags: javascript

I have a custom page that show a list of item generated by a view.

These items should link to each item page that is a custom page as well created by another view and that use contextual filter (id from url) to show it.

How can I link from the list to the specific view? The system says page not found (404).
I use this:

```
var link = l('' + row.title, 'pathview/' + row.nid);
```

`pathview/` is the path assigned in the view (if i write it in the browser it works)

The browser console show this in the link (72 is an example):

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:drupalgap_goto('pathview/72');" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r">Item Title</a>
```

Thanks in advance,
Cris.

Answer (score 1):

This docs page has a perfect example for what you need here: http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Views/Displaying_a_View/Views_Render_Array

The only difference is, first you need to create a page in your app that takes in a page argument (http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Pages/Page_Arguments).

Then when it comes time to render that page, add a `View` widget/render-array to your page. You'll configure that `View` widget to pull from `'pathview/' + nid`

Comment: Unfortunatelly it is not very clear to me how to do the page argument, everything is fine if is a node but when I try to load the views content and I create the page is not showing. Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Please update your question to include the code you are using to build these two pages, and I'd be happy to take a look, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've done some research and after a lot of try, these are my 2 pages:

## Custom module for the page with the list of items out of a drupal views

```
function mymodule_list_menu() {
  var items = {};
  items['articles'] = {
    title: 'Friend\'s list',
    page_callback: 'mymodule_list_articles_page'
  };
  return items;
}

/**
 * The page callback to display the view.
 */
function mymodule_list_articles_page() {
  try {
    var content = {};
    content['my_articles_list'] = {
      theme: 'view',
      format: 'ul',
      path: 'my-articles', /* the path to the view in Drupal */
      row_callback: 'mymodule_list_articles_list_row',
      empty_callback: 'mymodule_list_articles_list_empty',
      attributes: {
        id: 'my_articles_list_view'
      }
    };
    return content;
  }
  catch (error) { console.log('mymodule_list_articles_page - ' + error); }
}

/**
 * The row callback to render a single row.
 */
 function mymodule_list_articles_list_row(view, row, variables) {
  try {
      if (row.immagine.indexOf('http') > -1){
          img = {
              my_custom_image:{
                theme:'image',
                path:row.immagine,
                alt:'gift',
                title:'gift'
              }
            };
            img1 = row.immagine; 
        }else{
          var image_html = theme('image', { path: row.immagine.src });
          img = image_html; 
            img1 = "---"; 
        }
      var title_html = row.nome+" "+row.cognome.charAt(0)+"."+" "+row.title;
       var image_html = theme('image', { path: row.img.src });

      var link = l('' + title_html + image_html, 'singlegiftapp/' + row.nid);
      return link;

   }
  catch (error) { console.log('mymodule_list_articles_list_row - ' + error); }
}

function mymodule_list_articles_list_empty(view, variables) {

  return t('Sorry, no articles were found.');


}
```

## Custom module for the page with the single item after clicking one in the previuos list and that call another drupal views

```
  function mymodule_single_menu() {
  var items = {};
  items['singlegiftapp/%'] = {

    page_callback: 'mymodule_single_page',
    pageshow: 'mymodule_single_pageshow',
    page_arguments: [1]
  };
  return items;
}


function mymodule_single_callback(callback, nid) {
  node_load(nid, {
    success: function(node) {
      callback.call(null, node.title);
    }
  });
}

function mymodule_single_container_id(nid) {
  return 'gift-' + nid;
}

function mymodule_single_page(nid) {
 var content = {};
  content['divname'] = {
    theme: 'jqm_item_list',
    title: '',
    items: [],
    attributes: { id: 'divname' }
  };
  return content;
 }

function mymodule_single_pageshow(nid) {
  var path_to_view = 'singlegiftapp/'+nid;
  views_datasource_get_view_result(path_to_view, {
    'success':function(data){

    if (data.nodes.length > 0) {
        var items = [];

        $.each(data.nodes, function(index, object){
              var row = object.node;


             var image_html = theme('image', { path: row.img.src });

               var description =
                '<h1>' + row.title + '</h1>' +
                '<p> ' + row.field_anothertext+ '</p>';
               var dato = t(description+image_html);
              items.push(dato);

        });
         drupalgap_item_list_populate("#divname", items);
      }
    }




  });

}
```

These 2 module are working for me based on my views. Hope that would help to someone...